# Database driver & version after server upgrade

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The server I'm running Craft installations on just got an upgrade to Ubuntu 20 with MariaDB 10.5 Before MySql 5.7 was used.

When I look at the System Report in the Craft CP, it says: Database driver & version    MySQL 5.5.5
When I look at phpMyAdmin it says: "Server-Version: 10.5.6-MariaDB-1:10.5.6+maria~focal-log - mariadb.org binary distribution"

Why is it showing MySQL 5.5.5 in the System Report?

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB is a "drop-in" replacement for MySQL and Craft/PHP/PDO treats them as identical 99.99% of the time.

Craft gets the information about which database/version is being used directly from [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and since there isn't a specific MariaDB PDO driver, the MySQL is used and that is what is reported back.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm wondering about the version 5.5. Wouldn't MariaDB 10.5 not be more like MySQL 8.0?